# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. How to fix error when property sometimes IS MISSING?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a header (id="header") that appears on some pages.  If the Header is present, and the user clicks on a button, innerHTML should then be set to "Submitted".

However, since (id="header") is missing on some pages, the error above appears. What can I do to get rid of the error, given the code I have? (working on a huge old project, can't feasibly go in and add a header to all the pages at this point)

tried the code below, but still getting an error.

```
if (document.getElementById('header').innerHTML != null {
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = 'Submitted'
}
```

Comment: You need to check if the element exists. Not if it has content, which suggests it should exist.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check for the existence of the element before attempting to access `innerHTML` on it, e.g. like so:

```
if (document.getElementById('header')) {
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = 'Submitted'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use header without use `innerHTML` for see if exist like:

```
const header = document.getElementById('header');
if(header){
   header.innerHTML = 'YOURCONTENT';
}
```